# SceneKit - mesh unwrap

Tags: scenekit, mesh, parameterization, metalkit

How can I unwrap a SCNShape in SceneKit?

I need to do it in a way that I can “mirror” both, so when I change the 2D, the 3D meshes reflect the changes.

Is it possible to do it SceneKit? It not, maybe in Metal?

Thanks!

[image][image]

Comment: You can extract the vertex used to build the mesh, but what you do from there? it is difficult to say.. beyond I imagine trying to ensure the space between each vertex is the same maybe?